# docker daemon running on worker node inside a docker swarm listens to 443 and cannot run a service on this port

Tags: docker, swarm

`Docker` daemon running in a node inside a docker swarm listens to 443, and as a result when i try to run an `nginx` service on this port I'm getting errors that this port is already in use.

How can I start the docker daemon to listen in a different port?

When I drop the swarm, the `Docker` daemon stops listening to port 443.

Comment: Docker does not listen on port 443 out of the box. What configuration changes did you make to have it listen on this port?

Comment: Run `docker ps` and `sudo netstat -plant`. Add the output of above two commands on the node where you are facing the issue